# Android get edittext text programmatically

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, android-edittext

i have this code:

```
List<EditText> someList = new ArrayList<EditText>();

//Let's say we'd like to add 10 EditTexts
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    EditText t1 = new EditText(); //The EditText you'd like to add to the list
    t1.setText("lol"); //Give the EditText the value 'lol'
    someList.add(t1); //Add the EditText to the list
}

//Go over the list and get the values
for(EditText t : someList){
    String val = t.getText(); //Get the value for the temp EditText variable t
}
```

i would like to know how can i get the arraylist text with an index number? like: `somelist[2]`

Comment: Is it really necessary to save the EditTexts to the List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
int index = 2;
EditText et = someList.get(index);
Log.d(TAG, et.getText());
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
EditText t = someList.get(2);
String text=t.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
EditText text2=someList.get(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
somelist.get(2);
```

this will return the edittext at the position 2.